# Select all check boxes just from a table and not others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having some issues with a bit of code.

I am trying to select all the checkboxes from a table and not others.

I have some code running but this selects all the checkboxes from the page and I want only from a specific table. How do i tell my selectAll to just pick from this specific table?

My code is below or a Jsfiddle link here

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VladN/kh0Ls5w7/5/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#selectAll').click(function(event) {
    if (this.checked) {
      // Iterate each checkbox
      $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = true;
      }).change();
    } else {
      $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = false;
      }).change();
    }
  });

  $('.fixed_headers tr').click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
      $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
    }
  });

  $("td input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlighted");
    } else {
      $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("highlighted");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #E8EFFA;
}
.dialogTitle {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #F2F0E6;
  font: bold 8pt Tahoma Black;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #F2DCB1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #6C8CD9;
}
.header {
  background-color: #fffdf2;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: default;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.tableDiv {
  height: 50%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.tableTitle {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #D4DFFA;
  font: bold 9pt Tahoma Black;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  outline: 1px solid #6C8CD9;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.tableSection {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #D4DFFA;
  font: bold 9pt Tahoma Black;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.tableDiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 99%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  backgroun-color: #FF0;
}
.tableFunction {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #D4DFFA;
  color: #737373;
  font: 8pt Tahoma;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 0px;
}
.hd {
  margin-left: -2px;
  background-image: url('../img/BGButton_Image_00.gif');
  border-left: 1px solid #EBEFF3;
  border-right: 1px solid #EBEFF3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A8BBE0;
  text-align: left;
  color: #737373;
  font: normal 8pt Tahoma;
  padding-left: 4px;
  border-top: 1px solid #A8BBE0;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
.fixed_headers {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.fixed_headers td {
  border-right: 1px solid #EBEFF3;
  border-top: 1px solid #EBEFF3;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  height: 20px;
  font: normal 8pt Tahoma;
}
.fixed_headers tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f0f4fa;
}
.fixed_headers tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.fixed_headers tr.highlighted {
  color: #261F1D;
  background-color: #FFCC66;
}
.fixed_headers tr.header {
  height: 1px;
}
.fixed_headers tr.selectable:hover {
  color: #261F1D;
  background-color: #FFE8BA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="fixed_headers">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type='checkbox' id="selectAll" name='selectAll' />
      </th>
      <th>
        Two
      </th>
      <th>
        Three
      </th>
      <th>
        Four
      </th>
      <th>
        Five
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="checkbox">

<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: If someone's solution solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. For more info: [how does accepting an answer work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the selector to include only within `table`:

```
$('#selectAll').click(function(event) {
  if (this.checked) {
    // Iterate each checkbox
    $('table :checkbox').each(function() {            // «--- Changed here
      this.checked = true;
    }).change();
  } else {
    $('table :checkbox').each(function() {            // «--- Changed here
      this.checked = false;
    }).change();
  }
});
```

**Full Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#selectAll').click(function(event) {
    if (this.checked) {
      // Iterate each checkbox
      $('table :checkbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = true;
      }).change();
    } else {
      $('table :checkbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = false;
      }).change();
    }
  });

  $('.fixed_headers tr').click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
      $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
    }
  });

  $("td input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlighted");
    } else {
      $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("highlighted");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #E8EFFA;
}
.dialogTitle {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #F2F0E6;
  font: bold 8pt Tahoma Black;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #F2DCB1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #6C8CD9;
}
.header {
  background-color: #fffdf2;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: default;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.tableDiv {
  height: 50%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.tableTitle {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #D4DFFA;
  font: bold 9pt Tahoma Black;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  outline: 1px solid #6C8CD9;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.tableSection {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #D4DFFA;
  font: bold 9pt Tahoma Black;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.tableDiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 99%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  backgroun-color: #FF0;
}
.tableFunction {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #D4DFFA;
  color: #737373;
  font: 8pt Tahoma;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 0px;
}
.hd {
  margin-left: -2px;
  background-image: url('../img/BGButton_Image_00.gif');
  border-left: 1px solid #EBEFF3;
  border-right: 1px solid #EBEFF3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A8BBE0;
  text-align: left;
  color: #737373;
  font: normal 8pt Tahoma;
  padding-left: 4px;
  border-top: 1px solid #A8BBE0;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
.fixed_headers {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.fixed_headers td {
  border-right: 1px solid #EBEFF3;
  border-top: 1px solid #EBEFF3;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  height: 20px;
  font: normal 8pt Tahoma;
}
.fixed_headers tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f0f4fa;
}
.fixed_headers tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.fixed_headers tr.highlighted {
  color: #261F1D;
  background-color: #FFCC66;
}
.fixed_headers tr.header {
  height: 1px;
}
.fixed_headers tr.selectable:hover {
  color: #261F1D;
  background-color: #FFE8BA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="fixed_headers">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type='checkbox' id="selectAll" name='selectAll' />
      </th>
      <th>
        Two
      </th>
      <th>
        Three
      </th>
      <th>
        Four
      </th>
      <th>
        Five
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>image</td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="checkbox">

<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```

More elegant way would be using:

```
$('#selectAll').click(function(event) {
  var state = this.checked;
  $('.fixed_headers :checkbox').prop( 'checked' , state ).change();
});
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0b2nw4k/) for more info. Thanks to [user3613129](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3613129/user3613129).

Comment: May be a more elegant way to do this would be :

`$('#selectAll').click(function(event) {
    var state = this.checked;
      $('.fixed_headers :checkbox').prop( 'checked' , state  ).change();
  });`

Here is the updated fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/w0b2nw4k/

Comment: @user3613129 Yes, that looks great.

Comment: @user3613129 Added and given credits to you! `:)` Thanks.

Comment: Gracias! Very less people would do that :P

Comment: Thank you so much... I am quite new with web development and I can't quite grasp how far along you can go with the jquery selectors.. what you can and can't do.

Answer (score 2):

Use `table input[type=checkbox]` or `table :checkbox` instead of `:checkbox` for jQuery selector.
[Try in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harishkommuri/kh0Ls5w7/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this selector: `$('table.fixed_headers input[type=checkbox]:checked')`

Answer (score 0):

You can updated your selector to `table_class` + `input[type='checkbox']`. You can also get rid of entire `if..else` condition by using `self`.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/kh0Ls5w7/9/)

Correctly pointed out by @user3613129, of getting rid of `.each`

```js
$('#selectAll').click(function(event) {
  var self = this;
  $('.fixed_headers input[type="checkbox"]')
    .prop("checked", self.checked)
    .change();
});
```

Comment: You can also get rid of the `each` method as well :).

Comment: @user3613129 good point. have updated my answer and credited.